# After sending email, I receive a 419 page expired on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have a very annoying problem for a day at Laravel. I created a contact form on localhost and to send, I created a sending function inside the controller and a Mail. The problem is that as soon as I send the email, I am redirected to a page that says 419 Page Expired. I'm not using AJAX at the moment, just PHP.

In the HTML action attribute, I used the controller url to send email.

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="{{ url('/contact/send') }}">
                    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nome" required>
                        </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                        </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Mensagem" rows="12" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-circle btn-orcamento" id="submit-form" type="submit">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

In the controller, I have the function to call the view and the send function with a $request.

```
public function send(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required'
        ]);

        $data = array(
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'message' => $request->message
        );

        Mail::to('myEmail')->send(new SendMail($data));
        return back()->with('success', 'Sent with success..');
    }
```

In my Mail, I have the variable `$data` and the `build();`

```
public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('myEmail@outlook.com')->subject('Sending a test')->view('emailcontact')->with('data', $this->data);
    }
```

The emailcontact view is the message that will be sent in the email, basically there are only tags and the data variable. Regarding the .env file, I configured it with my email, outlook smtp and the rest.

Comment: Did you get the email?

Comment: No. I didn't receive the email.

Comment: Refresh the page and try again. Amd make sure you have an APP_KEY on env

Comment: As soon as I press the submit button, I am redirected to the 419 Page Expired error. 
I'm using localhost, APP_ENV is like: `APP_ENV=local`

Comment: App key, like `APP_KEY=khgdfgggfjhgggggdaart`

Comment: `APP_KEY=base64:andmessyletters`

Comment: Is it an error in the session.php file?
My SESSION_DOMAIN is null

Comment: Do you have `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),`?

Comment: Yes,`'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),`

Comment: I managed to solve it. It's a funny mistake. I was using `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`. But in the documentation, it said to use `@csrf` and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

You're using `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`, a meta tag meant [for the head of an HTML document](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) in the middle of the form.

If you wanted to use the `csrf_token()` that way, you'd want to use it in an input tag like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```